# Visualizing diagrams needed to compute $\operatorname{Tr}(A^3 (A^T)^3)$

Tags: matrix, visualization, combinatorics

I'm looking for help getting Mathematica code to construct diagrammatic expressions like the following, [obtained](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4818369/showing-e-operatornametraaatat-n3-2n) by River Li as a way to compute $\operatorname{Tr}(A^2 (A^T)^2)$ for $d\times d$ matrix $A$ with IID Gaussian entries.

[image]

The clearest explanation of such diagrams is given in Terry Tao's RMT [book](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf), Section 2.3.4.

He describes diagrammatic procedure for computing $E\operatorname{Tr}A^4$:
[image]
[image]

Which gives 4 different diagram types, that can be visualized method like above.

---

I'd like a method which takes an expression like $E \operatorname{Tr}(AAAA'A'A')$ where $A$ is a $d\times d$ matrix with IID standard normal entries, and generates a table of corresponding diagrams, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4RVo.jpg), hand-derived by River Li.

**Background**

For the last 4 years I've been slowly organizing Mathematica-related code that helps explain Gaussian expectations (starting with 2020 post [cumulants vis](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207183/generating-set-partition-diagrams)
, also post on [wicks brackets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/300724/visualizing-wicks-contractions-using-brackets), [partition lattice](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/232779/visualizing-set-partition-lattice)). I'm estimating I'm about halfway done to a nice [Wolfram Community](https://community.wolfram.com/web/yaroslavvb) post on combinatorics of random matrices.

Cross-[posted](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/3147322?p_p_auth=p2RsUNWz) to Wolfram Community, for more visibility from WRI employees

Comment: Why are there four identical graphs in the jpg image? All graphs are symmetrical by horizontal line except for two graphs. What is the logic behind this asymmetry?

Comment: The two different colored lines are because it's $AAA'A'$, so blue correspond to edges from $A$ and orange are edges from $A^T$. For $E\operatorname{Tr}(AAAA)$, there will be four diagrams with edges of the same color, corresponding to endpoint described in cases (i), (ii), (iii), (iv)

Comment: @Yaroslav I am asking why four graphs are identical https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec3NU.png. What is the point of having the same four graphs? There are some numbers on them which probably should distinguish them, but nevertheless they are same considering vertices and edges.

Comment: @azerbajdzan oh interesting, good point, those are equivalent so not sure why River Li made them four times, it could be connected to an algorithm he used to generate them

Comment: To use the diagrams (or at least the associated information) to find the expectation of the trace, won't you also need the expected value and frequency of each diagram?  Or is that a separate question?

Comment: @JimB yes I will need that as well at some point, solving the problem one bit at a time

Comment: How can you expect an answer when you do not know what you want.  Tao and the author of the hand drawn image (Sangchul Lee) does not seem to describe the same matter. Tao: "only terms that do not vanish are those in which each edge is repeated at least twice", Sangchul Lee: "configuration with $m(e) \equiv 0 \pmod{2}$". Number of edges at least two and number of edges that is divisible by two are not the same thing. So they can not coincide on the diagrams.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Tao describes diagrams for $\operatorname{Tr}(AAAA)$, Sanchul Lee's diagrams are for $\operatorname{Tr}(AAA^TA^T)$

Comment: But then I do not see how Tao's explanation of `Tr(AAAA)` should help with your question of `Tr(AAA A'A'A')` or `Tr(AA A'A')`. The rules they used are different. You still have not explained why there are four instances of the same graph in hand-drawn image. If we do not know the rules to create these graphs how can we answer the question?

Comment: @azerbajdzan I'm learning this stuff as well, and the responses on this forum have been helpful to me to learn in the past, this is why I post underspecified questions sometimes. I'm in the process of figuring out what the algorithm is.for diagrams, but the starting principle is that if you turn trace problem into sum of paths, there is natural grouping of these paths if we treat all edge labels as exchangeable

Comment: This is not really for you to take the time to answer my question but I'll ask anyway:  If the 4 types are those that do not vanish, isn't type (iii) equivalent to `a[i1,i2]a[i2,i3]a[i3,i4]a[i4,i1]/.{i2->i1,i3->i1}` which results in `a[i1, i1]^2 a[i1, i4] a[i4, i1]` which when taking the expectation results in 0 as not all terms have even powers?  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I think I found the clarification in Tao's reference:  $M$ is assumed to be symmetric.  That would explain why my example above isn't 0.  But you haven't made that assumption about symmetry for $A$.  If $A$ isn't symmetric, then is giving the Tao reference just to say that you want similar looking diagrams?

Comment: @JimB yes, those are different diagram types and it needs to be symmetric, but I think figuring out how to do one kind of diagram we'll make it easier to figure out the other kinds

Comment: Sorry I'm being slow.  Are you assuming that $A$ is symmetric or just $M$?

Comment: Terry taos diagrams assume symmetric, river Li  diagrams do not

Answer (score 9):

Explanation why some graphs appear more than ones:

It depends on the number of possible paths - some graphs have only one possibility, the graph below has four.

[image]

Functions definitions:

I borrowed `removeIsomorphicDoublePaths` from @Domen's answer.

`removeIsomorphicPaths` is variation of `removeIsomorphicDoublePaths`.

`edgesTagged` adds tags to edge for proper displaying in `Graph`.

`ef` is edge shape function.

```
removeIsomorphicDoublePaths[doublePaths_] := 
 Module[{doublePathsFlat, hashes, isoHashes}, 
  doublePathsFlat = Flatten /@ doublePaths;
  hashes = ToString@Values[PositionIndex[#]] & /@ doublePathsFlat;
  isoHashes = DeleteDuplicates[hashes];
  Part[doublePaths, First@FirstPosition[hashes, #] & /@ isoHashes]]

removeIsomorphicPaths[doublePaths_] := Module[{hashes, isoHashes},
  hashes = ToString@Values[PositionIndex[#]] & /@ doublePaths;
  isoHashes = DeleteDuplicates[hashes];
  Part[doublePaths, First@FirstPosition[hashes, #] & /@ isoHashes]]

nk[n_, k_] := n!/((n - k)!)

edgesTagged[e_] := Block[{po, v},
  v = {};
  If[(po = 
        Position[Append[Sort[Most@#], Last@#] & /@ v, 
         Append[Sort@Most[#], {#[[-1, 1]], _}]]) != {}, 
     AppendTo[v, Append[Most[#], Last@v[[(Last@po)[[1]]]] + {0, 1}]], 
     AppendTo[v, #]] & /@ 
   MapIndexed[Append[#, {1 + Boole[First@#2 > Length[e]/2], 1}] &, e];
  Join[Most@#, {Append[Last@#, Subtract @@ Most@#]}] & /@ v
  ]

arrow = Graphics[{Line[# + {-1, 0} & /@ {{-1, 1}, {1, 0}, {-1, -1}}]}];

ef = ({Thick, (RGBColor /@ {"#FF6B00", "#0094FF"})[[#2[[3, 
        1]]]], {Arrowheads[{{0.01, 0.5 + 0.01, arrow}}], 
     Arrow@BSplineCurve[{First@#, 
        If[#2[[3, 3]] != 0, 
         Mean@#[[{1, -1}]] + #2[[3, 3]]^2*(#2[[3, 1]] - 3/2) {0, 
            0.4 + 0.2 #2[[3, 2]]/Abs[#2[[3, 3]]]}, 
         Splice[Table[Mean@#[[{1, -1}]], 
            3] + {{-0.05 - 0.05 #2[[3, 2]], 0.3} + {0, 
               0.2 #2[[3, 2]]/2}, {0, 0.5} + {0, 
               0.2 #2[[3, 2]]/2}, {0.05 + 0.05 #2[[3, 2]], 0.3} + {0, 
               0.1 #2[[3, 2]]}}*Table[{1, (#2[[3, 1]] - 3/2)}, 3]]], 
        Last@#}]}} &);
```

Code to produce edges for all graphs.

```
do = 5;
tup = Prepend[#, 1] & /@ Tuples[Range[do], {do - 1}];
gr = GatherBy[#, Last] & /@ {removeIsomorphicPaths[tup], tup};
pairs = Flatten[Tuples /@ Transpose[gr], 1];
jp = Join @@@ Map[Partition[#, 2, 1] &, pairs, {2}];
edges = removeIsomorphicDoublePaths[
   Select[jp, AllTrue[Values@Counts[#], EvenQ] &]];
FullSimplify[
  Total[nk[n, Flatten[#] // Union // Length]*
      Times @@ ((Values@Counts[#] - 1)!!) & /@ edges]] // Apart
```

---

```
48 n + 28 n^2 + 28 n^3 + n^5
```

Code to display graphs:

```
Graph[DirectedEdge @@@ #, EdgeShapeFunction -> ef, 
    VertexStyle -> Black, VertexSize -> Tiny, 
    VertexCoordinates -> 
     Table[{n, 
       0}, {n, #[[All, {1, 2}]] // Flatten // Union // Length}], 
    ImageSize -> 
     200*(#[[All, {1, 2}]] // Flatten // Union // 
        Length)] & /@ (edgesTagged /@ edges) // Column
```

---

`do=2`

[image]

---

`do=3`

[image]

---

`do=4`

[image]

---

`do=5`

[image]

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fU48d.png)

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PD88.png)

---

Some interesting graphs for `do=6` out of all `559`

[image]

And another two interesting graphs for `do=6` where there is impossibility of having no crossings of edges.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure this is because I'm still not understanding these diagrams but why are there so many duplicate diagrams?

Comment: @JimB: Some graphs allow multiple paths, some allow only one path. So how many paths there exist in a graph that many times it appears in the list. So for example 2nd graph in the image for `do=4` allows four combinations of paths, 6th graph in the image for `do=4` allows only a single path.

Comment: @JimB I added animated explanation why some graphs appear more than once at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Looks nice, can you also include the code that produced your animations?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very *very* stupid, naive and brute-force approach. Unfortunately, I don't know how to control the position of graph edges, so the graphs are not as pretty as the ones you have. `SameStructureQ` is by [@lericr](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/300890/75628).

Because this is a brute-force approach, it gets slow and memory-intensive for larger $n$. I have managed to run it up to $n=5$, and the results match those of [@Roman](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/298260/getting-formulas-like-e-operatornametra3-at3-n410n24n/298293#298293).

```
d = 4;

(* Check whether two lists are isomorphic *)
SameStructureQ[a_, b_] := Values[PositionIndex[a]] == Values[PositionIndex[b]]

generatePaths[n_, d_] := Prepend[1] /@ Tuples[Range[n], {d}]
makeEdges[lst_] := DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[lst, 2, 1]

(* Generate all possible non-isomorphic paths of length d on n$ vertices *)
n$ = d + 1;
paths = generatePaths[n$, d];

(* Generate all pairs of paths and select only those that end in the same vertex *)
(* For smaller memory consumption, use the following instead: *)
(* doublePaths = ResourceFunction["SelectTuples"][
                  paths,2,Last[#[[1]]]==Last[#[[2]]]&]; *)
doublePaths = Tuples[paths, 2];

(* Select only those that end in the same vertex *)
doublePaths = Cases[doublePaths, {{__, last_}, {__, last_}}];

(* Select only those paths for which all edges appear even many times *)
doublePaths = Select[doublePaths, AllTrue[Values@
      Counts[Partition[#[[1]], 2, 1]~Join~Partition[#[[2]], 2, 1]], EvenQ] &];

removeIsomorphicDoublePaths[doublePaths_] := 
  Module[{doublePathsFlat, hashes, isoHashes},
   doublePathsFlat = Flatten /@ doublePaths;
   hashes = ToString@Values[PositionIndex[#]] & /@ doublePathsFlat;
   isoHashes = DeleteDuplicates[hashes];
   Part[doublePaths, First@FirstPosition[hashes, #] & /@ isoHashes]
   ];

(* Select only non-isomorphic double paths *)
doublePathsUnique = removeIsomorphicDoublePaths[doublePaths];

(* Make edges from vertex paths *)
edges = Catenate /@ Map[makeEdges, doublePathsUnique, {2}];

(* Calculate E *)
nk[n_, k_] := n!/((n - k)!)
FullSimplify[Total[nk[n, Max[Last /@ #]]*Times @@ ((Values@Counts[#] - 1)!!) & /@
     edges]] // Apart

(* Plot graphs *)
(* Edges connecting the same vertices need to have different tags if \
   you want them to be coloured differently. Hence "*". *)
annotateEdges[edges_] := Module[{m = Length[edges], edges1, edges2},
  {edges1, edges2} = Partition[edges, m/2];
  MapThread[
    Annotation[Append[#1, #2], 
      EdgeStyle -> ColorData[97][1]] &, {edges1, Range[m/2]}]~Join~
   MapThread[
    Annotation[Append[#1, ToString[#2] <> "*"], 
      EdgeStyle -> Orange] &, {edges2, Range[m/2]}]
  ]
vc = Table[i -> {i, 0}, {i, n$}];
Grid[GatherBy[
  Graph[annotateEdges[#], VertexCoordinates -> vc, 
     VertexStyle -> Black, EdgeStyle -> Thick, 
     EdgeLabels -> "EdgeTag", ImageSize -> 120] & /@ edges, 
  VertexCount], Alignment -> Left]
```

$$E_d:=\mathbf{E}[ \operatorname{Tr}( A^d (A^{\top})^d)]$$

---

$d=1: \quad E_1 = n^2$

[image]

---

$d=2: \quad E_2 = n^3+2 n$

[image]

---

$d=3: \quad E_3 = n^4+10 n^2+4 n$

[image]

---

$d=4: \quad E_4 = n^5+28 n^3+28 n^2+48 n$
[image]

---

$d=5: \quad E_5 = n^6+62 n^4+110 n^3+468 n^2+304 n$

*Large image with 559 diagrams ...*

---

Edit explanation: In the first version of my answer, I generated tuples only from non-isomorphic paths. However, this misses some allowed combinations (e.g. [these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SZxW.png) four were missing for $d=4$). Hence, I now generate tuples from *all* possible paths, and remove isomorphic ones afterwards.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the arrows and the colors of the edges are redundant. What matters is only number of (undirected) edges between pairs of vertices.

Comment: Colors represent different types of matrices. Tao considers only $A$, while Yaroslav have both $A$ and $A^\top$, that's why the two colors, and that's why you have to consider paths separately.

Comment: That looks quite promising! Since it matches the results I had before for d=2, d=3. How did you get the formula printed? I tried `FindSequenceFunction[%, xx]` and it returned unevaluated

Comment: The formula for specific $E_n$ is calculated (and printed) before the plots (look for the line `FullSimplify[...]`).

Comment: The formula is not printed when I run the code in question, here's what I see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzVAO.png)

Comment: @Yaroslav So it only works for `d=1,2,3` but fails for `d=4,5` and probably all `d>3`. So the question is where is the problem? Already in Sangchul Lee's method or the method is correct but there is a mistake in Domen's code?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, can you please try on a fresh kernel? azerbajdzan, what are you talking about? Where does it fail?

Comment: @Domen ah, newbie mistake, I had `n` defined, I see it now, thanks! I put up a little webapp which uses your code [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/jamie-diagrams.nb)

Comment: @Domen Correct formulas are `48 n + 28 n^2 + 28 n^3 + n^5` and `304 n + 468 n^2 + 110 n^3 + 62 n^4 + n^6` for `d=4,5`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan good catch, the formulas are actually correct only up to $n=3$, formulas for up to $n=6$ are given in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/298260/getting-formulas-like-e-operatornametra3-at3-n410n24n). You can see the first discrepancy for $n=4$ in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozQbS.png), and [this notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/domen-diagrams.nb)

Comment: What do you guys focus on? This is the first thing to do - to check whether results are correct.

Comment: @azerbajdzan be nice  the visualization result for n=2 are still nice, and we are all just hobbyists here

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, thanks for the reference! I'll try to fix my code :)

Comment: the correct link for the formulas up to $d=6$ is https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/298293/217

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, I have made a "minor" change in the algorithm (briefly explained at the end), and it seems the results are now correct.

Comment: @Domen thanks for the follow-up, I'm glad the results are matching up now

Answer (score 1):

This just an extended comment.

When $d=3$ $A$ is a $n \times n$ array of independent unit Gaussian random variables, the trace of $A^d (A^T)^d$ is the sum of products of the form

$$A_{i_1,j_1}A_{i_2,j_2}A_{i_3,j_3}A_{i_4,j_4} A_{i_5,j_5}A_{i_{6},j_{6}}$$

and for general $d$:

$$A_{i_1,j_1}A_{i_2,j_2}\cdots A_{i_{2d},j_{2d}}$$

It seems you want to know the combinations that have positive expectations (as that is what Tao finds for powers of symmetric matrices).  And finding out how often those combinations occur will apparently be addressed in a separate question.

From answers to one of your previous questions for any particular $d$ the multiplicity of each distinct element of $A$ has to be even for the expectation to be positive so one can determine the complete set of diagram types with the following:

```
diagramTypes[d_] := Select[IntegerPartitions[2 d], AllTrue[#, EvenQ] &]

diagramTypes[1]
(* {{2}} *)
diagramTypes[2]
(* {{4},{2,2}} *)
diagramTypes[3]
(* {{6},{4,2},{2,2,2}} *)
diagramTypes[4]
(* {{8},{6,2},{4,4},{4,2,2},{2,2,2,2}} *)
diagramTypes[5]
(* {{10},{8,2},{6,4},{6,2,2},{4,4,2},{4,2,2,2},{2,2,2,2,2}} *)
```

Comment: For `d=1` there are `2` diagrams and your formula is `{{2}}`  (which seems reasonable). For `d=2` there are `5` diagrams and your formula is `{{4},{2,2}}`. For `d=3` there are `19` diagrams and your formula is `{{6},{4,2},{2,2,2}}`. Can you explain how `{{4},{2,2}}` provides `5` diagrams and  `{{6},{4,2},{2,2,2}}` provides `19` diagrams?

Comment: @azerbajdzan  Good comment.  My understanding of the objective is to find a general approach that allows for the determination of the expectation of the trace of certain functions of a matrix $A$ as defined above.  My approach ends up with far fewer diagrams/cases as you've pointed out and I'll update my answer with a better description and rationale.  What will matter in the end is the ability to count the occurrences of diagrams with positive expectations in some structured way which is essential but not even asked yet.

Comment: @azerbajdzan In short, I'm not arguing that the diagrams don't exist.  But I think that they can be coalesced into the groupings I'm proposing if the objective is to find the combinations with positive expectations.  The "test" will be if the finer grained diagrams provide a formula for the counts of occurrence and my approach doesn't.